# webview paypal redirect, is it considered as in-App purchase to sell photos?

Tags: android, paypal, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-play

I know it is being asked many times but I just still not sure if it is applied in my case correctly.

My app is 100% webview based (google play) meaning it is connected to my online website where the user needs to upload his photo for processing and make paypal payment by redirect to paypal after his photo is uploaded to server. After payment the user will receive his processed photo back by email.

My question is if it is considered as in-App purchase and if it is prohibitted by google policy? I was trying to find this information but all I could find is 30% charges for in-App purchases.

Could someone be kind so kind to explain if I am allowed to do that with my app using PayPal redirect similar to buy it now button.

Thank you,